# making citrix run with squid

Tags: proxy, squid, citrix

**Scenario:** Our employees are on on-site assignment with company X. Company X has placed them behind a squid proxy for any internet-related access.

There are a couple of applications that our employees need to access via citrix hosted in our organization. If they access it using a data-card (so that they are directly on the internet), they can connect and work perfectly.

**Problem:** However, when they try to access our citrix 
site, they end up with

```
'Could not find Citrix Presentation Server' or 'The Citrix SSL Relay Name could not be resolved'
```

We managed to fix the second problem by opening up the 1494 port on squid and changing the .ica file by updating the following:

```
ProxyType=Auto  
ProxyUseFQDN=On
```

The Citrix support chaps said that unless the client machine cannot directly resolve and connect (in other words, has a 'route') to your citrix server, it ain't gonna work.

Has anyone out there got this working? If you done it by adding routes to the client machine, could you please tell me how to do it too? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Citrix server is directly on the Internet then you not be able connect to your Citrix server. As the company has blocked all direct connections. You have 2 options

1) Have the company setup a Socks Proxy, as this will allow you to resolve the external addresses.

You will need to add the following lines to your ICA file

```
ICASOCKSProtocolVersion=0
ICASOCKSProxyHost= "IP address of the proxy server"
ICASOCKSProxyPortNumber=1080
```

2) Setup a Citrix Web Interface at your site which will allow you to connect from any proxy server.

3) Allow routes/ports through the X Company firewall to your Citrix Servers

Comment: wouldn't just point 3 make the whole thing work (I already have ProxyType=Auto & ProxyUseFQDN=On)? Do I really need to set up a socks proxy?

Comment: The whole point of a Proxy server is to stops direct access to the internet. 

You are stuck between and rock and hard plate. There is no easy answer, The simplest way is to ask the company if they will setup a Socks Server and then you can add the above settings to an ICA file.

The only other option is to setup a Citrix Web Interface.

Hope this helps...